# Understanding Per Unit System

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, ac, three-phase, single-phase

I am having issues understanding the Per-Unit System calculation. I don't come from an exact power engineering background so I hope my question is not too stupid.
[image]

- For the calculation of base impedance and current, I found it using the two giving base values.
  Ib=500/4=125A , Zb=4k/125=32 ohms
- For the per-unit value of the resistor: I divided the actual value (400) by the base impedance (32) and the value is 12.5 p.u.
- For the part asking about the resulting current if connected this bus to the ground am not sure if I do understand it fully. I found the current by dividing the base voltage (4k) by the per-unit resistance (12.5) so >> I=4k/12.5 = 50 p.u.
- for the remaining two parts I am confused with the frequency given how to use it.  I could only found the actual inductance by using the base impedance so >> L(actual)=L(p.u) * Zb = 0.1 * 32 = 3.2 H.
  Not sure and feel like I am missing something. Also, I tried to look for material to understand how to solve the remaining two parts but I couldn't find any useful material.

I hope someone could help explain this to me. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You have made an error by not being careful about V vs kV. There are simple formulae for calculating inductance and capacitance given impedance in ohms and frequency. You need to find those and memorize them. Resistance and reactance  combined is expressed as a complex number or a phasor (phase vector). You need to learn the related math. You should be able to find a reference for that.